# Magento - Cannot run reindexing, missing column in database

Tags: magento

I'm running with an extension for my layered navigation, which worked well till I tried to update it to a never version. I'm not able to reindex the extension again, this is what i get from it:

```
2012-11-29T21:35:30+01:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'target.default_mask1' in 'field list'
Trace: #0 /var/www/site.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/site.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/site.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/site.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)
#4 /var/www/site.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)
#5 /var/www/site.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(734): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/local/Mana/Db/Helper/Data.php(146): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/local/Mana/Db/Model/Indexer.php(36): Mana_Db_Helper_Data->replicate()
#8 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(207): Mana_Db_Model_Indexer->reindexAll()
#9 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(253): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#10 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(124): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#11 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()
#12 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')
#13 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(348): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 /var/www/site.com/public_html/index.php(82): Mage::run('', 'store')
```

And this is the replicate:

```
2012-11-29T21:49:20+01:00 DEBUG (7): UPDATE: SELECT DISTINCT 'target'.'id', 'target'.'code', 'target'.'type', 'target'.'default_mask0', 'target'.'default_mask1', 'eav_attribute_additional'.'is_filterable' AS 'is_enabled', 'eav_attribute'.'frontend_label' AS 'name', 'eav_attribute_additional'.'is_filterable_in_search' AS 'is_enabled_in_search', 'eav_attribute_additional'.'position' FROM 'eav_attribute'
INNER JOIN 'catalog_eav_attribute' AS 'eav_attribute_additional' ON eav_attribute.attribute_id = eav_attribute_additional.attribute_id
INNER JOIN 'eav_entity_type' ON eav_attribute.entity_type_id = eav_entity_type.entity_type_id
INNER JOIN 'm_filter2' AS 'target' ON target.code = eav_attribute.attribute_code WHERE (eav_entity_type.entity_type_code = 'catalog_product') AND (eav_attribute_additional.is_filterable <> 0)
```

If however, I remove the 'target','default_mask1' part, I'am able to find the attributes. I also found the default_mask in eav_attribute, but I'm not able to figure out what exactly the problem is unfortunatly. Any help would be appreciated!

(The extension is Manapro seo layered navigation)

Comment: Did you disable the compiler before you updated the extension?

Comment: Yes the compiler was, and is, disabled

Comment: Why don't you contact extension developer and ask them for help/advice? All paid extension should have support.

Comment: hi Sergei, I did and got the support needed. The problem was that the "upgrade" was interrupted due to visitors on the site. I put down the site, removed the /includes/ folder, ran a script from the developer in the sql, re-cached, and all worked as a charm again! So a lesson to myself, always put down the site before upgrading extensions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the "upgrade" was interrupted due to visitors on the site. I put down the site, removed the /includes/ folder, ran a script from the developer in the sql, re-cached, and all worked as a charm again! So a lesson to myself, always put down the site before upgrading extensions!